trying to work with MPI but it outputs 'The batch file cannot be found' in cmd when I debug the file in Visual studio 2010
I am trying to install MPI on ms visual studio 2010 (our professor forced us to use 2010 version specifically probably for the privileges it offers that newer version don't idk) and it's driving me insane
I've done exactly as he told us, first I created a new c++ win32 project (yes I already have MPI and MPI SDK installed on my pc) than I edited the properties as follows:

changed 'Debugging mode' to 'MPI cluster debugger'
changed run environment to 'localhost/4'
added '$(MSMPI_INC);%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)' to the 'Additional include directories' in the 'C/C++' tab
added '$(MSMPI_LIB32);%(AddtionalLibraryDirectories)' to the 'Additional library directories' in the 'Linker' tab
added 'msmpi.lib' to the additional dependencies in the 'Input' section of he 'Linker' tab

but when I press 'Debug' four cmd windows flash and it outputs 'The batch file cannot be found'
this is a code sample I am trying to run:
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int rank, size;
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    printf("I am %d of %d\n", rank, size);

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}

what am I doing wrong ?  I have a homework due tomorrow.and I already tried running visual studio as an admin
thank you for any help in advance


have u run (set MSMPI) on cmd to setup mpi on environment variables?
if not u can include the library paths directly after installing mpi from

remove #include "stdafx.h".

I've tried steps from YouTube and it works for me https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L-xJreZ55aU&t=159s

if it didn't work just email me --> lilianshaddod@gmail.com



Hello Lilian, thanks for responding, it turned out I only needed to add: 'system("pause");' before 'MPI_Finalize();' after including the iostream library
